# Serving generic error page MVC - keep getting 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to serve a custom error page in an MVC2 app, which uses the ELMAH for error log ([elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/))

I can't seem to reference the page correctly.

The error page is located at `~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx`

In the web.config :

```
<system.web>  
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Shared/Error.aspx"/>
</system.web>
```

But when I cause an error, expecting the error page, I get:

```
The resource cannot be found.
Requested URL: /Shared/Error.aspx
```

smae result even if I modify `defaultRedirect` to `~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx`

What am I doing wrong ?

**edit**: I obviously don't want to redirect to an action. I just want to display a static generic error page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `defaultRedirect` to the path of a route that renders your error page, e.g.

```
defaultRedirect="/home/error"
```

Or a static HTML error page, e.g.

```
defaultRedirect="/error.html"
```

Comment: Tried that, same thing: `<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.html"/>` .... `The resource cannot be found. Requested URL: /Views/Shared/Error.html`

Comment: @baron - why do you insist on putting a static html page in a views folder?  Views are not static html.  These paths are blocked by MVC, you need to put the file somewhere else, like Chris showed you in his answer.

Comment: By default `~/Views/Web.config` is configured to block direct access to files in the Views folder.  Try moving the static error page to the root folder.

Comment: I've fixed it like that. But to be honest, it just seems strange to serve a static html error page like that. Rather than just pointing to where the file is, I have to write a new action in the Home controller Home/Error, and point it to serve the file?! Or am I misunderstanding you, and it was simply to put the static html page NOT in the views section and rather somewhere like Content?

Comment: That's right, you can put the static HTML file somewhere else.  The Views folder is blocked for security because they contain server-side code.